# Puppet can't find file of module

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

I have spun up a puppet server (5.0.0) using the [docker-compose example](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker-examples/tree/master/compose) and successfully brought up six clients (using the debian-provided puppet agent).

While I can provide files with raw content, e.g.

```
file { '/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf':
  ensure => present,
  content => "[Time]\nNTP=time.xxx.net\n",
  notify => Service["systemd-timesyncd.service"]
}
```

supplying the files via source does not work:

```
file { "/etc/default/grub":
  ensure => present,
  source => "puppet:///modules/debian-noquiet-grub/etc-default-grub",
}
```

The clients error out with

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Loudgrub/File[/etc/default/grub]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/debian-noquiet-grub/etc-default-grub
```

and the server with

```
2017-08-24 13:40:21,582 INFO  [puppetserver] Puppet Not Found: Could not find file_metadata modules/debian-noquiet-grub/etc-default-grub
10.161.xxx.zzz - - - 24/Aug/2017:13:40:21 +0000 "GET /puppet/v3/file_metadata/modules/debian-noquiet-grub/etc-default-grub?environment=production&links=manage&checksum_type=md5&source_permissions=ignore HTTP/1.1" 404 132 10.161.xxx.zzz 10.161.xxx.zzz 8140 6
```

The file locations are (inside the Docker container):

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp (site.pp)
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/debian-noquiet-grub/files/etc-default-grub (the text file)
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules (first element of puppet config print modulepath --section master --environment production)
```

What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure if this could be the problem, but dashes aren't allowed in module names.

Comment: @gf_ this indeed was the answer, if you can post it as an answer you will get the deserved upvote. Thanks!

Comment: So I did, glad it helped, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.1/modules_fundamentals.html#allowed-module-names) (and the comments):

> Module names should only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores, and should begin with a lowercase letter. [...]